# Custom query with category exclusion and post-meta "whitelist"

Tags: categories, custom-field, wp-query, post-meta

I have two widgets, one shows **News** while the other shows everything except News (We'll call the second one **Blog**). The blog portion is currently working correctly.

The News posts are either categorized as `In the News` OR have the custom post meta `in-the-news`, set to 1. It's important to note that not all posts will have the custom post meta defined.

The main problem I am facing is that I need to compare post meta based  on whether the post is categorized one way or another.

**I may need to do a custom database query for this behavior, at least for the News.** Is it possible to do a custom query and convert it to a standard WP_Query object?

---

### What I have tried

Query for **News**.

**Problem:** Only shows posts within category 75 that have `in-the-news = 1`.

**Desired result:** Show all posts from category 75 regardless of the value of `in-the-news`, and any additional posts from outside the category which have `in-the-news = 1`

```
query_posts(array(
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'cat' => "75", // Only posts within category 75 (News)

  // Including posts tagged to show "In the News"
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'key' => 'in-the-news',
      'value' => '1',
      'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array( 
      'key' => 'in-the-news',
      'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
      'value' => '',
    ),
  )
));
```

Here is the query for the **Blog**:

This query appears to be working correctly, showing all posts outside of category 75, and hiding posts with `in-the-news = 1`.

```
query_posts(array(
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'cat' => "-75", // All posts EXCLUDING those in category 75 (News)

  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'key' => 'in-the-news',
      'value' => '0',
      'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array( 
      'key' => 'in-the-news',
      'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
      'value' => '',
    ),
  )
));
```

---

### Solution

Thanks to `s_ha_dum` for the amazing examples, here is the final query I am using. The logic here is that we do a custom MySQL query for an array of post IDs, then do a standard WP_Query using the returned IDs.

**Note:** The logic here was a bit more complicated than the original post. Basically, we originally had "News" and "Blog". But now we also have "Risk". Also, the `in-the-news` post meta was changed to `show-in-blog` as we reverse the functionality. I can't expect anyone else to ever understand the reasoning for this in the first place, as even I think it is ridiculous (But the client wants it, so be it!)

Here is my query, for the "Blog" widget. Slight variations are made for the "News" area. I'm not sure if the query could be cleaned up. I'm also not sure if it's a bad idea to perform so many SELECTs within the same query.

```
global $wpdb;

$query = // Splitting the SQL query to it's own code block for syntax highlighting!
```

---

```
  SELECT `ID`
  FROM {$wpdb->posts} posts
  WHERE (

    /* Exclude posts in News (94) 
       Ignore show-in-blog option for News here, 
       as News is displayed on the same page */
    94 NOT IN ( 
      SELECT `term_taxonomy_id` 
      FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships}
      WHERE `object_id` = posts.`ID`
    )

    AND

    /* Exclude posts in Risk (96), 
       But show Risk posts that have the postmeta "show-in-blog" */
    (

      96 NOT IN ( 
        SELECT `term_taxonomy_id` 
        FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships}
        WHERE `object_id` = posts.`ID`
      )
      OR
      (
        96 IN ( 
          SELECT `term_taxonomy_id` 
          FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships}
          WHERE `object_id` = posts.`ID`
        )
        AND
        1 IN (
          SELECT `meta_value` 
          FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
          WHERE 
          `meta_key` = 'show-in-blog'
          AND `post_id` = posts.`ID`
        )
      ) /* OR */

    ) /* AND */

  ) /* WHERE */

  ORDER BY `post_date` DESC;
```

---

```
$args = array(
  // Only include IDs returned by the above query
  'post__in' => $wpdb->get_col( $query ),
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

get_template_part('loop', 'frontpage');
```

Comment: thanks for this, really helped me on my current problem. just a note: you don't even need your own `WP_Query`, you could set your `post__in` parameter via `pre_get_posts` filter, a little bit similar to the filter used by s_ha_dum..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do a custom query and convert it to a standard
>   WP_Query object?

Yes. You can do something like...

```
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE ....");
$posts_qry = new WP_Query(array('post__in'=> $posts_ids,'orderby' => 'post__in'));
```

The second query will preserve the order of results from the first.

I am fairly sure that you cannot make that first query with `WP_Query`, or any other function. The logic is too complicated. You'd need a `JOIN` or a `WHERE` clause that `WP_Query` does not support. Unfortunately, writing that `SQL` is going to be complicated too, just to get the category.

Completely hand-writing the query is of course your first option. The best I can do without hand-writing any `SQL` would be:

```
$post_ids = new WP_Query(array(
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'cat' => "75", // Only posts within category 75 (News)
));

$post_ids_2 = new WP_Query(array(
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'post__not_in' => $post_ids->posts,
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => '_edit_lock',
      'value' => '0',
      'compare' => '=',
    ),
  )
));
$post_ids = $post_ids->posts + $post_ids_2->posts;
$posts_qry = new WP_Query(array('post__in'=> $posts_ids,'orderby' => 'post__in'));
```

That is 3 queries (ouch) and ordering could be an issue if you are worried about that.

Your other option is alter the query via a couple of filters. The `WP_Query` arguments are going to deal with the `in-the-news = 1` part.

```
$post_ids_v3 = new WP_Query(array(
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
  'my_variable' => true,
  // Including posts tagged to show "In the News"
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'in-the-news',
      'value' => '1',
      'compare' => '=',
    )
  )
));
```

Notice that you are leaving out your category component and passing an extra unofficial parameter named `my_variable`. *I do not know if passing additional variables like that is by design, so be aware that that may be unofficial behavior.* You are going to use that to add your category component into the query with two filters.

```
function posts_join_wpse_98652($join,$qry) {
  global $wpdb;
  if (true === $qry->get('my_variable')) {
    $join .= " JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id)";
  }
  return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join','posts_join_wpse_98652',1,2);

function posts_where_wpse_98652($where,$qry) {
  global $wpdb;
  if (true === $qry->get('my_variable')) {
    $where .= " OR {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id IN (75)";
  }
  return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where','posts_where_wpse_98652',1,2);
```

That is not even close to well tested, but it appears to be working when I try. Still, these things can be hard to get right, maybe I've made a mistake. Barely tested. Possibly buggy. Caveat emptor. No refunds.

Comment: Wow, these are some extremely clever solutions! The first example was sufficient in my case, I am comfortable enough writing a custom MySQL query for this sort of thing. In total, script and DB, only two queries are used! I did have to use a few additional queries within the first query, but I think that's normal, isn't it? -- The second option would look better to a PHP developer, but I've commented the SQL enough that it shouldn't be an issue down the line. The third option would be preferred on a larger project, didn't know you could do that. Anyway, it's working now, thanks very much!