# Complex WP_Query Using Post Date And Post Meta

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, query, date

I am using Wordpress as a CMS on a website which has standard posts, a custom advert post type and a custom event post type. The event post type has some custom meta which stores the event start date.

I am attempting to make a feed of all three post types on the home page (i.e. index.php). The standard posts and advert posts need to be ordered by their post date, but the events need to be ordered by their start date and slotted into the feed in the correct position.

Is it possible to run a query which selects all three post types and two of the post types by post date and one post type by a meta value? I'm currently using this query to bring in the standard posts and advert posts:

```
if (is_home() && $query->is_main_query())
    $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'ecs_adverts'));
```

Comment: The first thing you should probably consider is using `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts()` -- see [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) and its accepted answer for details.

Comment: I don't have time to think much about this but there was what I think is a similar request from not too long ago that might prove helpful. I will check back later if I can. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98748/21376

Comment: @PatJ - my bad. I realised that `query_posts()` was no good after my original post. I've updated the question to reflect my code changes.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - thanks for the suggestion. I didn't realise you could merge queries like that, that might just do it.