# Order by meta_value_num DESC and meta_value ASC on WP 4.0

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I have created a custom post type that I want to order by

1. `custom-field-1`, which is boolean so its value is either `1` or `0`, in `DESC` order (1 to 0)
2. `custom-field-2`, which contains text and is supposed to be ordered `ASC` (A to Z)

**First Question:**

A more powerful ORDERBY-parameter was introduced in WordPress 4.0. Can this be made using the new ORDERBY functionality?

**If not, second Question:**

What's the best approach? How would I make a `meta_query` order the posts by `custom-field-1` in descending order and then by `custom-field-2` in ascending order?

**Edit:**

Or would it be an option to use two instances of `WP_Query`, one for the posts with `custom-field-1 value = '1`' and one for those with value `0` ?

I know this "order by multiple custom field values" has been discussed a lot here, but I did not find a similar question I could adapt when I was searching the site before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the new `orderby` parameter is great in `WP_Query`, it does not support multiple `orderby` for multiple `meta_key`'s.

I've went through a couple of scenarios and even went and digged into trac and make and came up with the following

- make.wordpress.org [A more powerful orderby in wordpress 4.0](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/)
- [trac ticket #17065](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17065)

None of the issues regarding this very problem have been answered. It also seems from those two links that there is an issue ordering by a `meta_key` and another field like post date for instance. I haven't tried this as yet.

I truelly think that you have two choices here without creating two queries.

- hack using the `posts_orderby` filter as described by @s_ha_dum in his answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101599/31545)
- By making use of PHP ordering using `usort`. The idea here would be to sort your query by one `meta_key` and then take the returned posts array ($posts) and sort them by the second `meta_key` before the loop starts. You can either use the `the_posts` filter (just remember to remove the filter once done) or simply unset `$posts` in your template and set it with the reordered array of posts once done

Comment: Thanks Pieter, that's useful information. Can the `posts_orderby` filter be combined or used within i.e. a `pre_get_posts` filter ?

Comment: For interest sake, were you able to get a working solution to this?

Comment: Yes I did, I needed to use the function along with a search/filter plugin so it differs a little from a wp-only solution. I will edit my solution to make it independent from the plugin and post it soon. I can say the solution is strongly inspired by the link to @s_ha_dum's answer you posted

Comment: Great, looking forward to your solution.

Comment: I didn't have the time to edit my solution to this question - but I accepted this answer because it led to my solution.