# Sort custom post type by multiple custom fields

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, sort

I have 4 text fields in a custom post type. How can I sort the posts by this order of text fields: `brand_fbn` - `model_fbn` - `year_fbn` - `plate_number`?

This is my code, which isn't working:

```
$ins = new WP_Query( array(
    "post_type" => "application-list",
    "author"    => $current_user->ID,
    "meta_key"  => array( "year_fbn", "plate_number" ),
    "orderby"   => "meta_value ",
    "order"     => "ASC"
) );
```

I know this line won't work: `"meta_key" => array( "year_fbn", "plate_number" )`

Comment: Does this help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101599/21376

Comment: You can try this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67387/how-to-order-custom-post-type-by-multiple-custom-fields